# Can't log SSR errors with Nuxt

Tags: express, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to catch a rendering error (HTTP 500) that happens on a certain route within a Nuxt (v2.17.2) project.

The app is hosted with the following Firebase Cloud Function:

```
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt-start');

let isReady = false;
exports.renderApp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!isReady) { isReady = await nuxt.ready(); }
    await nuxt.render(req, res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error during SSR:', err);
    res.redirect(302, '/custom-error');
  }
});
```

But it never reaches the `catch` block in the problematic route. Instead, it just returns the default Nuxt2 error page.

I also could not find any relevant documentation to `nuxt-start` that explains if `nuxt.render` can return an error or just handles it by default.